# Xamarin.Android: ConstraintLayout unresolved attributes in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use ConstraintLayout in a fresh installation of Visual Studio. I added **Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout.Solver** packages from Nuget.

I tried to declare a very simple and small UI in XML, but the ConstraintLayout-specific attributes cannot be resolved by the IDE. The attributes such as `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` are underlined in blue and the Error List window gives this explanation:

> The
>   'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf'
>   attribute is not declared.

Interestingly, the code does compile, but as long as the IDE won't resolve the attributes, intellisense won't work and it's a pain to develop in such circumstances.

Is there anyone who has encountered a similar issue?

My example code excerpt is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
      android:id="@+id/cardView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPaleYellow"
      app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/proposal_card__name_button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
          android:text="Button"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: [Please refer this to add `ConstraintLayout` to your project](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97631/how-to-use-constraints-layout), I follow it and it works for me great, although there are green underlines.

Comment: Visual Studio android ui designer will usually show this. The question is does it work?

Comment: The code compiles, but when auto-complete isn't there, manually coding everything is a huge pain. Android Studio never fails in such basics.
@NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio designer is not as great as Android Studio. One thing you can do is create a sample project in Android Studio with all the required resources and design there and copy the whole layout when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Constraint Layout. Here is a sample using the "ConstraintLayout" element

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    


    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:id="@+id/view1"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"  
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        android:text = "Button 1"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can't post directly, but basically switch Linear to ConstraintLayout